# Add security rules to let users read data that contains their uid only in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I wrote these security rules in my firebase console to let projects and contacts get read and write permissions only if the logged in user's uid matches the projects and contacts uid value. I verified the matching uids but no projects nor contacts are visible anymore.

```
{
  "rules": {
     "Projects" {
         "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
          }
      },
     "Contacts" {
         "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Note: each Project contains a value that has the user's uid.

My Database Structure:

```
my-database:
   - Projects
      -MYGDH884934939
         uid: xxxxxxx
   - Contacts
      -MYGDH535578889
         uid: xxxxxxx
```

Logged in user has same uid = xxxxxxx

Comment: I suggest making an attempt at this using what you find in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions).  If you are stuck, edit the question to explain exactly what part of this you are unable to express, and show what your database looks like in more detail.

Comment: I searched high and low in the docs. Nothing seems to make sense to me. If you know the answer in a couple of lines i would greatly appreciate. thanks

Comment: If you are stuck, edit the question to explain exactly what part of this you are unable to express, and show what your database looks like in more detail.

Comment: I edited my OP with what the docs say to do but when i do this, no projects are visible to anyone.

Comment: The child nodes starting with "-MYG" are not UIDs at all.  They are random push IDs.

Comment: right so how do i say if those child nodes' uid value is equal to auth.uid?

Comment: @DougStevenson i edited my OP, can ypu please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Projects": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
              }
      },
"Contacts": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
              }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried this but nothing showed up for any user. Strange

Comment: the uid is not a direct child of Projects, How can i say if the uid is a child of an element in tthe Projects array?